# I can only send files with wifi direct the first time after connection

Tags: android, wifi-direct

I'm trying to exchange files between two devices using android wifi direct. Any of the device can send and receive files. After discovering and connecting the two devices,I can only successfully send and receive a file/files upon the first time calling `send`. I'm unable to send any file afterwards. In addition,transfer speed is very slow(it takes about three minutes to transfer a 10mb file)

```
    void startServer(){
    
        String intRoot = new FilesDisplayFragment().internalDirRoot;
        ExecutorService serverExecutor = newSingleThreadExecutor();
        serverExecutor.submit(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
                try {
                    serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8888);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    socket = serverSocket.accept();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                BufferedInputStream bis = null;
                try {
                    bis = new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(bis);

                int filesCount = 0;
                try {
                    filesCount = dis.readInt();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                File[] files = new File[filesCount];

                for(int i = 0; i < filesCount; i++)
                {
                    long fileLength = 0;
                    try {
                        fileLength = dis.readLong();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    String fileType = null;
                    try {
                        fileType = dis.readUTF();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    String fileName = null;
                    try {
                        fileName = dis.readUTF();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    if (fileType == "apk"){
                        File dirs = new File(intRoot + "RemoteView/" + "app");
                        if(!dirs.exists()) dirs.mkdirs();
                        files[i] = new File(dirs.toString() + "/" + fileName);
                    }


                    FileOutputStream fos = null;
                    try {
                        fos = new FileOutputStream(files[i]);
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);

                    for(int j = 0; j < fileLength; j++) {
                        try {
                            bos.write(bis.read());
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });

    }

    void startClient(Intent intent){
        socket = new Socket();
        String intRoot = new FilesDisplayFragment().internalDirRoot;
        Parcelable parcelable = intent.getParcelableExtra("hostAdd");
        Parceler parceler = Parcels.unwrap(parcelable);
        String hostAdd = parceler.getGroupOwnerAddress().getHostAddress();
        ExecutorService clientExecutor = newSingleThreadExecutor();
        clientExecutor.submit(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(hostAdd, 8888), 5000);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                BufferedInputStream bis = null;
                try {
                    bis = new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(bis);

                int filesCount = 0;
                try {
                    filesCount = dis.readInt();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                File[] files = new File[filesCount];

                for(int i = 0; i < filesCount; i++)
                {
                    long fileLength = 0;
                    try {
                        fileLength = dis.readLong();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    String fileType = null;
                    try {
                        fileType = dis.readUTF();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    String fileName = null;
                    try {
                        fileName = dis.readUTF();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    if (fileType == "apk"){
                        File dirs = new File(intRoot + "RemoteView/" + "app");
                        if(!dirs.exists()) dirs.mkdirs();
                        files[i] = new File(dirs.toString() + "/" + fileName);
                    }


                    FileOutputStream fos = null;
                    try {
                        fos = new FileOutputStream(files[i]);
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);

                    for(int j = 0; j < fileLength; j++) {
                        try {
                            bos.write(bis.read());
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        });
    }

    void send(Intent intent){
        Parcelable parcelable = intent.getParcelableExtra("selected_wifi_files");
        Parceler parceler = Parcels.unwrap(parcelable);
        File[] files = parceler.getSelectedFilesWifi();
        ExecutorService sendExecutor = newSingleThreadExecutor();
        sendExecutor.submit(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                If(bos == null){
                BufferedOutputStream bos = null;
                try {
                    bos = new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(bos);
BufferedOutputStream bos = null;
                try {
                    bos = new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(bos);
 
                }
               
                try {
                    dos.writeInt(files.length);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                for(File file : files)
                {
                    long length = file.length();
                    try {
                        dos.writeLong(length);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    String fileType = FilenameUtils.getExtension(String.valueOf(file));
                    try {
                        dos.writeUTF(fileType);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    String name = file.getName();
                    try {
                        dos.writeUTF(name);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    FileInputStream fis = null;
                    try {
                        fis = new FileInputStream(file);
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);

                    int theByte = 0;
                    while(true) {
                        try {
                            if (!((theByte = bis.read()) != -1)) break;
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        try {
                            bos.write(theByte);
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: All those catch blocks. Very good. But if there is a cath you continue as if nothing has happened. Instead you should stop and inform the user about the catch.

Comment: `bos.write(bis.read())` Indeed that makes the transfer slow reading and writing one byte at the time.

Comment: It is inclear when you call send() and it is even unclear for what you would use that function. And if it was used by server or client

Comment: @blackapps the function can be used by both server and clients to send files

Comment: And when? You are not using it. Nor are you telling which code you use the second time. We hardly know what you do. You should exactly tell your scenario that leads to a problem.

Comment: It is hard to believe that you can transfer any file as the server tries to receive/read files when a client connects. And a client also tries to do the same upon connecting. And send() is nowhere called so no file is sent.

Comment: @blackapps but it works the first time. I want both server and client to be able to receive and send files like you have in file transfer apps. Of course,I call the send method when I want to transfer. It's not written here.

Comment: Then write it here too. All is hard to believe. And tell who is first sending. And who is first receiving. Tell your scenario. How many files sent first time? Why do i have to ask all this? You should have told all at first.